# Pass Webform Submission Back to Form Template

Tags: theming, webforms

I'm trying to use a webform to accept data, do some processing and calculation, and pass it back to the user. For user-friendly purposes I don't want to redirect to a confirmation page, but back to the form page so they can enter the information again. So essentially, I want the form template to submit back to itself, and if it has received a submission, print out the results (for now). I'm having trouble finding a way to do this.

I have an override template (`webform-form-9.tpl.php`) in my theme folder and it is successfully overriding the default, however I can't find any **any** way to actually get the values the user just submitted - even printing **all** available variables doesn't display the submission. I can't even seem to check **if** the user submitted a form or not. Does the form template not even receive the submission data? That seems ***extremely*** peculiar if so, so I can only imagine I'm not just not getting it right.

Any advice here?

Comment: So I've managed to get the data displaying on the form template by redirecting the form to a custom URL consisting of the current URL (the form template) and the sid of the submission, then getting the submission data through nid and sid. But I still want to keep the form populated with the info they entered, whereas when the page reloads, the form fields are empty. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your webform, so the "redirect URL" is the following:

```
node/[node:id]/submission/[submission:id]
```

Now after submission you will see the result overview page of that submitted form